# How to organize folders on a repo?

Tags: github

On my repo hosted on [Github](https://github.com/) I have uploaded my files and it now resembles the following:

[image: folders]

I would like if these folders were to appear in the same way as they appear on my desktop.

To specify in `Numerical` order,

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ... 100

My research on accomplishing this, revealed this feature has yet to be implemented ([ex](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3551), [ex](https://github.com/atom/tree-view/issues/691), [ex](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/895)).

According to the following stack question:

[How do you control the order in which files appear in a GitHub gist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665267/how-do-you-control-the-order-in-which-files-appear-in-a-github-gist)

The folders are by default sorted in `ASCIIbetical` order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The folders are by default sorted in ASCIIbetical order.

Exactly what I mentioned indeed.

That means you need to come up with a different naming convention, which would allow the natural sorting order you are after.

Example:

```
001
010
011
012
100
```

And, [as I mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15442368/6309), you can rename a file directly on GitHub if you want.

Comment: I had not thought about doing this! Thank you for your response.

Comment: Further I learn: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861651/how-to-rename-a-directory-folder-in-githubweb/32620165

Comment: @aitía Indeed, well done. I mentioned that in 2013: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15442368/6309